# Load data from text file with ajax/javascript into html problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, text-files

I want to load data from this text file that is in the same folder as the html file on my computer but it won't work.  In process of learning Ajax and put together this little test for myself *test.html* and the text file *test.txt*.  Any advice please, would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script>
function loadData()
{
var test;
test=new XMLHttpRequest();
test.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (test.readyState==4 && test.status==200)
       {
       document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=test.responseText;
       }
    }
test.open("GET","test.txt",true);
test.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadData()">Get data</button>
</body>
</html>
```

When I press the button, nothing happens.  On the site where I saw a similar example the data from the text file is displayed above the button.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely to be that you're accessing the files directly on your local system; web browsers have been designed not to allow this in order to prevent saved web pages loading personal files from your disks and uploading them to remote servers.  In order to make it work, you'll need to run a web server locally and use that to view the files.  I recommend the Apache web server, which is flexible and can be used on Windows, Linux or OSX.

Comment: Yep, that seems to be it.  I uploaded the html and data file to my hosting server and it worked. Yes, I would like to run a web server locally but don't know which version of Apache to download. Thanks :)